# Android: Increase adb debug timeout in android studio

Tags: android, debugging, adb, usb-debugging

Application gets closed when I am debugging the app in Android Studio.

Actually, I am facing an issue when I am doing debug to my android app in Android Studio. Application is getting close at some of the breakpoint execution. These app close breakpoints are not same every time. App debug mode is not happening more than 2 minutes, after a time period ADB debug connection finish.

I don't know this is due to the ADB connection timeout problem or something else?

I found this link [Increase Android Emulator Timeout time](http://code2care.org/2015/increase-android-emulator-timeout-time/) for the Eclipse but nothing for Android Studio.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Emulator Set timeout value:

[image]

First Open **Android Studio**
You have to move in **File** -> **Setting**
Then Click on Task option from the vertical-left sidebar.
Then the **Connection timeout** option should be there.
In textbox you can specify your value in milliseconds.
By default it **5000 milliseconds** but you can changed it.

Comment: This appears to be a setting for issue tracking server timeout. What does it have to do with adb?

Comment: This also help for the Layout Inspector capture time out

Comment: doesnt work for me. With any value here the debugger closes in the same time

Comment: The default 5000 milliseconds implies a 5 second timeout, not after 2 minutes.

Comment: I was able to get around by disabling the "Show value tooltip" setting, by default it was on and set to 700 Millis for me. I turned this off and am able to debug now without the debug connection dropping. Located via: `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Data Views`. I lose the tooltip but at least I can debug now